# how can i define a macro/function in cmake to read parameter list?

Tags: cmake

I want to write a function in cmake.

it looks like:

```
macro(compile arg1)  # TODO here: define a endless input param
  target_link_libraries(${arg1} pthread zmq config++ mmm dl)   # TODO here: to add input list
endmacro(compile)
```

for example:

i want to compile a pragma named `demo`, it need library `libb` and `libc`

so i called: `compile(demo, b, c)`

please notice. the arg num is not fixed. so, i need a thing similar with  `char ** argv` in c++

the first input parameter will set the binary file name, the left will be library name.

How can i do this? can you help on this? thanks

Comment: Just a note for future readers: This question is *not* about the C++ preprocessor and its macros, but the macros defined in a `CMakeLists.txt` file used by CMake itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But then the c++ tag is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Please read [the `macro` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html), especially [the section about arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#arguments). Also note [the differences between macros and functions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#macro-vs-function), especially when it comes to arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There's `ARGN` available which allows you to access all parameters after the last named one. Note that parameters are separated by one or more whitespace characters, not by commas for all cmake commands including macros.

```
macro(compile TARGET_NAME)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} pthread zmq config++ mmm dl ${ARGN})
endmacro(compile)

...

compile(demo b c)
```

Not sure if this case justifies creating a macro though, since you could simply do

```
target_link_libraries(demo pthread zmq config++ mmm dl b c)
```

Furthermore I do recommend specifying `PRIVATE`, `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` when linking libraries via `target_link_libraries`.